# Comparing two shapes in Createjs

Tags: createjs, easeljs

Is there a way to determine whether two Shape objects are the same? By same I mean they have same shape and size, preferably (but not necessarily) also same x and y?

Comment: Could you show an example of the two Shape objects/instances you're trying to compare?
My guess is that you'll have to compare their properties, eg `if (shape1.x === shape2.x)`, etc.

Comment: That is, you have to define the criteria for "same" and compare the two objects that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no comparison method, so like @Calculuswhiz pointed out in the comments, you would have to write a function to do the comparison. For most display objects, you would need to compare x, y, scale, rotation, and skew (or do a matrix comparison), and then for graphics, you would have to iterate the `.graphics._instructions` array to compare each graphic instruction.

If this is a critical function of your app, it might make sense to modify each graphic command to have an `equals` method for easier comparison.

Comment: Thanks. That's a helpful piece of information. This function is indeed pretty critical for my app, but the use case more complex as one of the compared shapes is in fact created from adding up several other shapes (it's a tangram-like game), so I don't really have an x, y or rotation for it. I guess I'll have to think of another solution, but at least I know the options now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put small invisible circles at the points of your shapes then loop through them all to see if they hit all the little circles at the points of another shape?  If they do then they could be said to be the same.  We do something like that for blob hit tests and we have had people compare user made blobs in this manner https://zimjs.com/hittestpath.html